# What should I do after my application has been forwarded to someone else?

Tags: professionalism, management, job-search, hiring-process, recruitment

Long story short, here is my snipped LinkedIn conversation. I am applying for a job.

Me:

> Mr. X,
>
> First of all, apologies for the unsolicited message. We connected a 
>   while back around [technology], and having followed [company] for some
>   time,  when I came across one of the company's job postings I was very
>   interested in applying.
>
> Having sent a recruiter (external) my CV and info, I was assured that
>   my  profile was a good match for the position (as a tools developer),
>   and we  discussed the technical test phases. Unfortunately it has been
>   around 3  weeks with no response at this point, and I am unable to
>   raise a  response.
>
> -redacted; basically listed why I am interested-
>
> I realise this is an unorthodox approach, but I didn't want to pass up
>   this opportunity and with you as a contact, I hoped to reach out and 
>   make my interest known. For sake of convenience, please find my CV 
>   attached.
>
> If there is a suggested route to continue the process, please do let
>   me know.
>
> Kind regards, and thank you for reading,
>   -Me

CEO:

> X added Y to this conversation
>
> Thanks for reaching out [me].
>
> CC'ing in Y who handles all talent applications here at [company].
>
> Always best to come direct to us I think, so you are doing the right
>   thing.
>
> Best regards
>
> X

Me:

> That's great to hear.
>
> Thank you both, much appreciated.
>   -Me

Now, I am *highly* vested in getting this position, it's a job I want to carry out very much, for this company specifically. This is certainly not helping me in not overthinking, hence seeking out you good people.

I assume at this point I am supposed to wait for their talent manager to reply to me, but it's been a couple of days now. I am beginning to question whether I should have followed up with more details, or contacted her directly as well. Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated, as I'm worried now that time is of the essence in the event that I should be following up. **Do I just wait? Do I follow up? Do I reach out to their talent manager directly?** I think I provided enough detail given that they only seem to be looking for a single tool developer, as it's in a specialised area, but as always I'm my own worst enemy and I'm probably putting way too much thought into it all.

Also, as a side note, as I attached my CV to the CEO's message and it seems he read it, I am certain that this isn't a case of not being suited to the position (as with the first recruiter, apparently working on their behalf). That aside, as mentioned in the messages, they run tech tests (one of which lasts several days).

Comment: Hi and welcome to Workplace SE! I've edited the title of your question to be more descriptive as it was rather vague and general. Hope that helps!

Comment: Is there an online application route as well for this position? I think you should fill that as well if it is there, just to make your application more formal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's nothing else you need (or should) do at this point - they have your details, they know you're interested in the position and why and you've had an encouraging response.

The next move is theirs. Following up or contacting the talent manager directly is unnecessary and **could actually harm your chances** - nobody likes to be nagged!

Comment: @Daedalus if it's the "Always best to come direct to us" line that is making you worry I wouldn't - that is referring to the fact that you contacted them direct after not hearing back from the recruiter as opposed to any suggestion for further action

Comment: @motosubatsu agree as of the current status - after some time though (2 weeks?) it may be acceptable to inquire along the lines *Is this opportunity still live? Can I have a rough estimate of when you will make a decision so I can plan accordingly?*